# Redirecting webpage to some pre-defined webpage in case of errors

Tags: php, html, apache, redirect

Suppose the user try to access the following web page on my website

`http://something.com/hello/hi.php`

But `hi.php` webpage does not exists on the server. Instead of web-browser showing that "this page does not exist", I want to redirect the user to some predefined page (say nofound.php) on which I will beautifully display the message "**page you are trying to access does not exists**"

How can I redirect a user to some predefined web-page in case of "**page not found**" error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a directive in your .htaccess file.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /your4040page.html
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Apache you can take a look at [ErrorDocument directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument).

Many frameworks (Symfony, CakePHP, Rails,...) implement their own mechanisms to handle 4xx and 5xx errors (among others). You can take a look at them as well and adapt them to your particular requirements.